# mysql results if no records in join table

Tags: mysql, join, null, records

I looked en searched but could not find an answer.
I need to see the records in houses_houses if there are no matching records in houses_availability.
I know it has something to do with IS NULL but all I tryed failed.
Please help.

```
SELECT 
    houses_houses.*, 
    houses_availability.from_date 
FROM 
    houses_houses 
LEFT JOIN 
    houses_availability ON houses_houses.sid=houses_availability.housesid 
WHERE 
    houses_availability.from_date>='2015-09-05' 
AND 
    houses_availability.until_date<'2015-09-11'  
ORDER BY houses_houses.sid LIMIT 0, 9
```

Comment: Small point, you are selecting houses_availability.from_date , but you appear to want to only include rows where there is no houses_availability row. Hence that fields would always be NULL for any returned rows.

Answer (score 0):

You check for NULL on the LEFT OUTER JOINed tabled in the WHERE clause:-

```
SELECT 
    houses_houses.*, 
    houses_availability.from_date 
FROM houses_houses 
LEFT JOIN houses_availability 
ON houses_houses.sid=houses_availability.housesid 
AND houses_availability.from_date>='2015-09-05' 
AND houses_availability.until_date<'2015-09-11'  
WHERE houses_availability.housesid IS NULL
ORDER BY houses_houses.sid LIMIT 0, 9
```

Important to note that you should not check any of the columns from the LEFT OUTER JOINed table in the WHERE clause, as that would exclude the whole row AFTER the join, rather than excluding the LEFT OUTER JOINed tables row BEFORE the join. Hence check the date range in the ON clause

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your houses_availability criteria in JOIN .. ON clause:

```
SELECT houses_houses.*, houses_availability.from_date 
 FROM houses_houses 
 LEFT JOIN houses_availability ON (houses_houses.sid=houses_availability.housesid AND houses_availability.from_date>='2015-09-05' 
  AND houses_availability.until_date<'2015-09-11')
 WHERE 
  houses_availability.housesid is null
ORDER BY houses_houses.sid LIMIT 0, 9
```